# Taking a string and formatting into table

Tags: string, powershell, csv

I have the output of an `Invoke-SSHCommand` command for a host that gives me the following info in the form of a string:

```
PS C:\Users\user> $t.Output
system> Machine Type-Model             Serial Number                  UUID
--------------                 ---------                      ----
8871AC1                        XXXXXXX                        ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUV
system>
```

Does anybody have any advice or hints as to how to take the above output and manipulate it to a CSV or something that would give me the functionality of the following:

```
PS user> $t.Output.UUID
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUV
PS user> $t.Output.Serial
XXXXXXXX
```

At the moment, the most I can do with it is below:

```
PS C:\Users\user> $t.Output.Get(0)
system> Machine Type-Model             Serial Number                  UUID
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How did you assign/obtain `$t` in the first place?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Sorry, wasn't sure if that info was relevant: `$t` is the output of an `Invoke-SSHCommand` command

Comment: And what command are you actually running remotely with Invoke-SSHCommand?  It vaguely looks like a PowerShell command's output.  Is it?  [Hint: This is why you usually want to post all relevant code, not just the bit you're having trouble with.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `$t.Output` is not an object, but rather an unstructured text, hence you can't use `ConvertTo-Csv`, you first have to create a structured object from your unstructured text. This is what `ConvertFrom-String` is for.

### Example

```
$tObject = $t.Output | ConvertFrom-String -PropertyNames 'Machine Type-Model', 'Serial Number', 'UUID' | Select-Object -Skip 2 
$tObject | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation
"Machine Type-Model","Serial Number","UUID"
"8871AC1","XXXXXXX","ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUV"
```

Comment: **Important Note**: `ConvertFrom-String` does not exist anymore in *Powershell* as [it is proprietary code](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/726#issuecomment-477768876) only available in *Windows Powershell* and has never been reimplemented as open-source code in Powershell